# How do I name my react component to accommodate an element in my nested JSON?

Tags: json, reactjs, forms, components

I'm using React 16.13.0  I have the following component (src/containers/FormContainer.jsx) ...

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      defaultCountry: 484,
      countries: [],
      provinces: [],
      newCoop: {
        name: '',
        type: '',
        ...
      },


    ...
  render() {
    return (
        <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

            <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Name'}
                   name= {'name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.name}
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}

            <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Type'}
                   name= {'type'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.type}
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative type'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Type of the cooperative */}
```

My Input copmonent, src/components/Input.jsx, looks like such ...

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor={props.name} className="form-label">{props.title}</label>
    <input
      className="form-input"
      id={props.name}
      name={props.name}
      type={props.type}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    />
  </div>
)
}

export default Input;
```

The issue is I need to submit a POST request where the "type" parameter is submitted as the following JSON ...

```
{
    "name": "1872",
    "type": {
        "name": "Coworking Space"
    },
    ...
}
```

How do I name my second input field (the "type" field) such that I can submit my JSON with the proper structure?

**Edit:** The handle input and submit functions ...

```
  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let coopData = this.state.newCoop;

    fetch('/coops/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(coopData),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(response => {
        response.json().then(data =>{
          console.log("Successful" + data);
        })
    })
  }
  handleClearForm() {
    // Logic for resetting the form
  }
  handleInput(e) {
       let value = e.target.value;
       let name = e.target.name;
   this.setState( prevState => ({ newCoop :
        {...prevState.newCoop, [name]: value
        }
      }), () => console.log(this.state.newCoop))
  }
```

Comment: The easy way would be to change the data shape in `handleFormSubmit`. Can you also share that code?

Comment: @bamse, added the functions as an edit to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to form object in `this.handleFormSubmit` method, this will be easy, you have to just form the object as per your requirements.

  ```
  handleFormSubmit = () => {
    //form json object as per required structure
    const formData= { 
      name: this.state.newCoop.name, 
      type: {
        name: this.state.newCoop.type
      }
    }

   // then send formData in axios or fetch ajax method.
  }
  ```

> UPDATE

- I agree with @bamse about scalibilty, now i have changed the solution for better scaling.
- In this solution, **no need of installing** any other package.
- You just need to add one more function to read `name` from input component where you can assign `{name:"type.name"}` in dotted format.

---

```
    handleInput = (e) =>{
      let self=this
      let value = e.target.value;
      let name = e.target.name;
      //update State
      this.setValue(self.state.newCoop,name,value) 
    }

     setValue = (obj,is, value) => {
       if (typeof is == 'string')
         return this.setValue(obj,is.split('.'), value);
       else if (is.length==1 && value!==undefined)
         return this.setState({obj: obj[is[0]] = value});
       else if (is.length==0)
         return obj;
       else
         return this.setValue(obj[is[0]],is.slice(1), value);
      }
```

> - INPUT COMPONENT changes:  `name= {'type.name'}`

### --------- ------------------------------------END-----------------------------------------

- The reason why are you not getting Object in your structure is, you have given `name= {'type'}` in INPUT component.

  - So when you handle type input field in `handleInput` method, the `let name = e.target.name;` is `"type"`.
  - When you setState in `{...prevState.newCoop, [name]: value }`. Here the `[name]` is `"type"` which is key of `newCoop`. SO it will update `type` key directly. Because your passing `name= {'type'}` in INPUT component

Comment: Hi @heisenberg, Right now I have "body: JSON.stringify(coopData)," in my fetch/Ajax call.  Would I continue to use that "stringify(data)" method with the formData JSON you created?

Comment: hi @Dave , yes you have to stringify data in body while using fetch otherwise data will be sent in [object] format. If you use axios call you don't have to stringify data. axios call is clean compare to fetch. you can give visit at https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.

Comment: Thanks.  The form appears to submit with the correct JSON format, however, one thing I'm noticing is that it is impossible to type values into the address fields, e.g. "street".  Whenever I type in there, the characters don't show up.  They show up for other fields, like "name" or "web_site."  Here's the entire code if you're interested -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps/tree/master/client

Comment: hi @Dave, I have seen your code.  There were few mistakes. I have done few changes in FormContainer.jsx. I have provided two way of setting data in state. 2nd way is in FormContainer_2.jsx file. You can go through both formContainer file. Hope you like it. Thanks.  the link is here for zipped code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UCQzk4oG3UnXGbCbTAEUz6jlUl-outag

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to achieve this but I see 2 are within reach

#### 1. Keep `newCoop` in the structure you need for your POST call

```
this.state = {
  newCoop: {
    name: '',
    type: {
      name: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Change the value you give to the type input

```
<Input inputType={'text'}
  title= {'Type'}
  name= {'type'}
  value={this.state.newCoop.type.name}
  placeholder = {'Enter cooperative type'}
  handleChange = {this.handleInput}
/>
```

And adjust `this.handleInput` to handle this case:

- you might need to write a dedicated `handleTypeNameChange` function
- change `this.handleInput` in a way that it can handle this case

This depends on your `this.handleInput` function - can you share it?

The `name` you give to your input is the html `name` attribute. Not sure if you use it in `handleInput`.

#### 2. Leave the form as it is an handle the data shape change in `this.handleFormSubmit`

```
this.handleFormSubmit = () => {
  const postData = { 
    name: this.state.newCoop.name, 
    type: {
      name: this.state.newCoop.type
    }
  }
  // POST postData
}
```

Again, this depends on you `handleFormSubmit` code.

Hope it helps!

---

> More details on option 1:

I like this approach. @heisenberg proposed a solution for this but that doesn't scale well - it works, but adding a few more fields would turn that code into something difficult to read and maintain.

You could:
 * use the path to the state value you want to update for the input name
 * in `handleInput` you update the state value located in the path specified by `name`

You could write an `handleInput` like this:

```
import { set } from "lodash";
[...]
  handleInput = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    const newCoop = set(this.state.newCoop, name, value);
    this.setState({ newCoop });
  };
```

I used lodash's [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) for this. There are other ways to do it - you could even write it yourself if you really don't want extra dependencies.

In order for this to work for `newCoop.type.name` you have to adjust the input's name

```
<input
  ...
  name={"type.name"} // <- use the path to the value you want to change
  value={this.state.newCoop.type.name}
  ...
/>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dust-xqg55?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is a Codesandbox with a working example. For simplicity I used a regular `input`, not a component.

Comment: I liked what you said in your first suggestion here (keep for structure of POST call) so I made the change to set the type value to "{this.state.newCoop.type.name}", however when the POST request is submitted, type is still getting submitted as 'type: "myType"', when how it actually needs to be submitted is 'type: {name: "myType"}'.